# Getting more details from a JavaScript error event handler

Tags: javascript, events, error-handling

I have made a simple popup image viewer. You can see a demo page for it here:
http://caerphoto.com/quickslide/

and the actual JS here:
http://caerphoto.com/quickslide/quickslide.js

I am trying to add a *useful* error handler to the image object created in the `setPopup()` function (line 169 or so), but it's proving difficult. Registering the handler works fine, and when something goes wrong, the handler fires.

The problem is, unimportant things like 'wrong MIME type' count as errors, at least on Windows (seems fine in OS X, in Chrome and FF4), so the error message pops up every time even though the image loaded just fine.

**Is there some way to determine what the actual error was, so I can filter out the important ones (e.g. 404s) and respond accordingly?** To clarify, I'm asking about handling an *error event*, not a JavaScript exception.

I've tried inspecting the error object passed to the handler, but it doesn't appear to contain any useful information.

---

#### edit:

It appears I was mistaken about the cause of the error – it turns out that this line was causing it:

```
popupImg.src = "";
```

The question is still stands, however – it'd be useful to know exactly what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [error object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/error) in a Mozilla browser?  You can always wrap things in `try...catch`([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#try...catch_Statement)) blocks to see your exception details, which provides quite a bit of information.

```
try {
 var t = a.notexists + b.thisisnotreal;
} catch (e) {
 /* do something with the error */
}
```

The error object has limited utility with IE, you get some non-standard stuff but it isn't really doing you any favors.  With Mozilla, there are some non-standard properties worth mentioning, specifically `stack` and `lineNumber` - most useful for debugging.

Comment: The problem is I'm not trying to catch a JavaScript exception, I'm listening for an *error event*.

Comment: You should get the same error object passed to your error handler - this is all the more error information you're going to get from Javascript.

Comment: Shame, as it's really doesn't contain any useful information - all I can say to the user is "Something went wrong. It might be x, y or z." :(